# Adding Drop down inside gridview header

Tags: asp.net

I am new to ASP.net and trying to add dropdownlist and search text boxes under my header fields  in Gridview control.

```
<asp:GridView ID="EmpGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
        DataKeyNames="EMPLOYEEID" 
        AllowSorting="True" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="50"
        OnPageIndexChanging="EmpGridView_PageIndexChanging" style="margin-right: 52px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="EmpGridView_SelectedIndexChanged"   

    > 
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="EMPLOYEEID"
            HeaderText="Employee ID" ReadOnly="true"
            SortExpression="EMPLOYEEID" />



            <asp:BoundField DataField="PERSONNAME"
            HeaderText="Person Name" ReadOnly="true"
            SortExpression="PERSONNAME" />

            <asp:BoundField DataField="DIVISIONNAME"
            HeaderText="Division Name" ReadOnly="true"
            SortExpression="DIVISIONNAME" />


                    <asp:BoundField DataField="DESIGNATION" 
                            HeaderText="Designation" ReadOnly="true" 
                            SortExpression="DESIGNATION"     
                         />

            <asp:BoundField DataField="CNIC"
            HeaderText="CNIC" ReadOnly="true"
            SortExpression="CNIC" />

        </Columns>


    </asp:GridView>
```

I want following

```
EMPLOYEEID            PERSONNAME              DIVISIONNAME          <----HeaderText

TextBox control       TextBox Control         DropDownlist control  <------aspcontrols
 ..data                ..data                   ..data              <------ rest is db
 ..data                ..data                   ..data
```

Meaning I want my labels there too with my asp.net controls
How should I do it?

So far I tried following but could not work out where to place it? since if I add it separately then there are rows of each control which  I don't want and boundfield tag does not permit it in it.

```
              <asp:TemplateField>
                  <ItemTemplate>
                      <asp:TextBox ID="searchBox" runat="server" />
                  </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use HeaderTemplate of the TemplateField for placing the controls on the header

```
<asp:TemplateField SortExpression="PERSONNAME">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <asp:Literal runat="server">Person Name</asp:Literal>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="searchBox"></asp:TextBox>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Literal runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PERSONNAME") %>'></asp:Literal>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Hedge plz also tell me if u have time how to make that text box searchable or other control that u may recommend for this purpose?

Comment: Similarly, you can add a button to the header. In the gridview's RowCommand event, get the textbox using  EmpGridView.HeaderRow.FindControl("searchBox") as TextBox.